# How to display a message and close settings window in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and I want to be able to have a response when the 'done' button is clicked, the settings window should close and the user would receive a message :

Here is the code for the settings page:
**settings.html**

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/settings.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <title>SSS- Settings</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card__header">
               <div class="toolbar">
                  <div class="toolbar__item toolbar__item--close"></div>
                  <div class="toolbar__item toolbar__item--min"></div>
                  <div class="toolbar__item toolbar__item--max"></div>
.....................................................(other settings)
<br>
                     <div class="buttons"><a href="#"></a><button onclick="closeFunction()" id = "save_settings" class="button">Done</button></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="../assets/js/settings.js"></script>
      <script>
      function closeFunction() {
          close();
      }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**settings.js**

```
console.clear();

toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
const fno = document.getElementById('fake-news-opt');
const hso = document.getElementById('hate-speech-opt');
const cbo = document.getElementById('click-baits-opt');
const pwo = document.getElementById('profanity-words-opt');
const save_button = document.getElementById('save_settings');




.............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my understanding, you are trying to close the window when the "DONE" button is clicked, if so:
You can remove the `onclick` attribute from the button tag and attach an `EventListener` to the button itself like so:

```
save_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    close();
}
```

Comment: In your settings.js file.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Any idea on how also to send a notification that the settings have been updated?

Comment: Do you mean like an alert?

Comment: No not an alert just a message that says "the settings have been updated" that uses the chrome.notifications lib

Comment: You could start off by defining a `title` variable and give it the value of whatever you want and an options variable.
Once you've done that you could do this
`registration.showNotification(title, options);`